# delete last character of filenames in a folder

Tags: sed, awk, sh

I have a folder that contains some text files. I need to delete the last character of each filename in this folder. filenames are shown below.

```
1ADFG.txt
RG25A.txt
5SDFC.txt
```

Desired output

```
1ADF.txt
RG25.txt
5SDF.txt
```

Comment: If it is not a homework but real task for user, it would be much more practical to use your favourite editor (Vim / Emacs) and tool like `vidir` from `moreutils` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do like this:

```
for i in *.txt; do echo "mv '$i' '${i/?.txt}.txt'"; done
```

If the output looks good, then pipe it to `| sh`, that is:

```
for i in *.txt; do echo "mv '$i' '${i/?.txt}.txt'"; done | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="."} {print substr($1,1,length($1)-1) "." $2;}'
```

feeded with the list of the names should do the job, provided that there's only 1 dot, the one for the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `sed` like this :

```
$ ls -1
1ADFG.txt
5SDFC.txt
RG25A.txt
$ ls -1|sed "s/\([A-Za-z0-9]\{4\}\)[A-Za-z0-9]*\(\.[A-Za-z0-9]\)/\1\2/g"
1ADF.txt
5SDF.txt
RG25.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is to use the perl `rename` utility:

```
$ rename -n 's/.\./\./' *.txt
1ADFG.txt renamed as 1ADF.txt
5SDFC.txt renamed as 5SDF.txt
RG25A.txt renamed as RG25.txt
```